# Resize jQuery to auto script works ... on all links

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, width

I am trying to get a rollover script to resize my social network links from a 32px square icon to the same icon, plus the trailing address.  So if I hovered over my Facebook link, the link would go from

`[f] [t] [g]`

to

`[f /facebookpage] [t] [g]`

and Twitter would go from

`[f] [t] [g]`

to

`[f] [t @twitter] [g]`

Here is the script I am using:

```
$(function(){
    var network = $('.social-networks li a'),
    animateTime = 75,
    navLink = $('.social-networks li a');
    navLink.hover(function(){
        if(network.width() === 32){
            autoWidthAnimate(network, animateTime);
        } else {
            network.stop().animate({ width: '32' }, animateTime);
        }
    });
})
function autoWidthAnimate(element, time){
    var curWidth = element.width(), // Get default width
    autoWidth = element.css('width', 'auto').width(); // Get auto width
    element.width(curWidth); // Reset to default width
    element.stop().animate({ width: autoWidth }, parseInt(time)); // Animate to auto width
}
```

On single icons, I've obviously got no problems, but when I have multiple icons, it resizes them all.  I've tried `$(this).find('.social-networks li a')`, but that hasn't worked (returns the same thing), and `$(this).children('.social-networks li a')` does nothing.  Is there a way to select only that particular element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hover function you should be animating $(this) instead of caching network. The this variable will refer to the hovered element, then wrap it in a jquery object to use jquery animation. Your network variable is probably an array containing all of the social icons

```
$(function(){
                var network = $('.social-networks li a'),
                    animateTime = 75,
                    navLink = $('.social-networks li a');
                navLink.hover(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if($this.width() === 32){
                        autoWidthAnimate($this, animateTime);
                    } else {
                        $this.stop().animate({ width: '32' }, animateTime);
                    }
                });
              })
              function autoWidthAnimate(element, time){
                  var curWidth = element.width(), // Get default width
                      autoWidth = element.css('width', 'auto').width(); // Get auto width
                  element.width(curWidth); // Reset to default width
                  element.stop().animate({ width: autoWidth }, parseInt(time)); // Animate to auto width
              }
```

Comment: Oh, you are a star. Thank you.